# How to map NGINX server_name to match any path of the domain

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx

I want to make my location to server from any path of my domain. Currently, I can make it work for the main domain and subdomain.

```
server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;
```

I would want something like

```
server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com *.mydomain.com/any/path;
```

Any comments or answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Only the domain name part appears in the `server_name` directive. The path name part is handled by the `location` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for more.

Comment: I have this location set:
`location ~ \.html$ { root index.html; }` but the nginx error log occurs: `/var/www/my-project/users/sign_in` no such file or directory.
PS: My project is a Rails app.